# Envío de datos de un formulario HTML a una base de datos MySQL usando Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, express, ejs

````js
```
const app = require('./server/server');

require('./public/datos')(app);

//inicializar el server
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('server on port', app.get('port'));
});

```
````

esta es la primera app web que desarrollo usando solamente Node.js y diversas herramientas como Express, MySQL y demás, pero tengo el problema de que no sé cómo enviar correctamente los datos del formulario HTML a la base de datos he estado rompiéndome el coco por días sin saber como resolverlo.

Al principio todo parece bien incluso el servidor funciona, la página carga en el navegador a la perfección que, pero no envía datos a la base de datos.

Si necesitan más información por favor pídanla soy nuevo en Stack Overflow

Use ejs como motor de vistas

````
const app = require('./server/server');

require('./public/datos')(app);

//inicializar el server
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('server on port', app.get('port'));
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/" class="container"  method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Numero de la Tarjeta</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Ntarjeta" name="Ntarjeta" placeholder="introduce el numero de la tarjeta" autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Lista de tiendas</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="tienda" name="tienda">
              <option>Gran Señora</option>
              <option>Dita</option>
              <option>Globo</option>
            </select>
          </div> 
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Productos</label>
          <input type="textarea" class="form-control" id="productos" name="productos" placeholder="Lista de productos">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" onclick="getElement" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
      </form>
      <!--tabla de BBDD-->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
               <table id="tablaArticulos" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
               <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Numero de tarjeta</th>
                    <th>fecha</th>
                    <th>Tienda</th>                                
                    <th>Productos</th>                      
                </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
               </tbody>
               </table> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>        
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {   
         var url = 'localhost:3000/datos';

          $('#tablaArticulos').DataTable({            
              "ajax":{
                  "url": url,
                  "dataSrc":""
              },
              "columns":[
                  {"data":"Ntarjeta"},
                  {"data":"fecha"},
                  {"data":"tienda"},
                  {"data":"productos"},
              ],
              "columnDefs":[{
                  "targets":[2],
                  render(v){
                      return Number(v).toFixed(2)
                  }
              }]
          });
    });
</script>
      </table>               
               

                  



  <script>
    document.getElementById('Ntarjeta').focus();
  </script>            
</body>
</html>


```


Este es el archivo introducir el código aquí datos.js que estoy utilizando donde creo que está el error
````

```js
const dbconexion = require('../config/dbConexion');

module.exports = app => {

    const connection = dbconexion();

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM TARJETAS', (err, result) => {
          res.render('view', {
            view: result
          });
        });
    });

    app.post('/', function (req, res) {
        const { Ntarjeta, tienda, productos} = req.body;
        connection.query('INSERT INTO TARJETAS SET?', {
          Ntarjeta, 
          tienda,
          productos
        }, (err, result) => {
          res.redirect('/');
        });
    });
}
```